# ¿Cómo puedo realizar la conexión mediante PDO a SQL Server 2016?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Uso Xampp en su ultima versión y mi intención es hacer un CRUD sencillo en PHP y SQL Server 2016, sin embargo, no tengo idea acerca de como se realiza la conexión a PHP mediante PDO.

Nótese que no uso ningún Framework como laravel, solo MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conectar PDO a SQL Server debes asegurarte que tu servidor tiene los drivers PDO correspondientes. Para evaluar esto, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$pdodrivers = \PDO::getAvailableDrivers();
print_r($pdodrivers);
```

En la salida resultante debe existir `dblib`. Si no existe debes instalarlo. Luego puedes instanciar el PDO de esta manera (las variables host, name, user y pass deber existir):

```
<?php
$connStr = "dblib:host=$host;dbname=$name";
try {
    $pdo = \PDO($connStr, $user, $pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    echo "No es posible conectar a la base de datos mediante PDO.";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Esta es la información que tiene el manual de PHP sobre DBLIB: http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Answer (score 0):

Te mando un ejemplo del que utilizamos aquí en el trabajo,  este es el código de un compañero, me lo proporciono. Hay varios caminos para PDO, este es solo un ejemplo, si estas conectando a una base de MySQL. Es recomendable guardar los argumentos en variables para reutilizar el código, así, si tienes mas formularios o necesitas mas conexiónes, solo llamas al archivo de conexión con un "requiere nombre_del_archivo_de conexión".

- Vas a necesitar descargar los drivers para realizar la conexión.
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
- Aquí te envío también un manual para que puedas configurar la conexión. 
  https://www.phparch.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/PDO__MSSQLServer.pdf

Saludos.

```
<?php
    $_MYSQL_HOST = "localhost"; //servidor
    $_MYSQL_DB = "base_prueba"; //base de datos
    $_MYSQL_USER = "root"; //Usuario
    $_MYSQL_PASS = "password"; //Password

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $_MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . $_MYSQL_DB .';charset=utf8', $_MYSQL_USER, $_MYSQL_PASS);  //parametros de conexion
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //atributos para la base de datos
    echo 'LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS SE REALIZÓ SATISFACTORIAMENTE
';
} catch (PDOException $e) { // captura de errores
    echo 'ERROR AL CONECTAR A LA BASE DE DATOS' . $e -> getMessage(); // mensaje de errores
    die(); //finalizar script 
?>
```

Comment: El OP indica para SQL Server, pero en tu enunciado hablas de MySQL. Revisando la 2da. referencia, a partir de la página 8 indica como es la accesibilidad, pero viendo el código de ejemplo no comprendo donde encaja. Copio lo indicado por @Awes0meM4n: _"Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia. Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia."_